# Remove line if empty after character

Tags: sed

How to remove line if characters do not exist after a symbol (e.g. `@`)?

E.g.

```
hello@lawyer
B@b
smith@
Nac@gyo
treat@
```

Lines `smith@` and `treat@` will be removed as there are no characters after `@`.

I would post sample of my experimentation -- but have been so far off the mark that would be unhelpful.

Answer (score 2):

using the delete command `d` and the `$` anchor that matches the end of the line:

```
sed '/@$/d' file
```

`/@$/`: when this pattern succeeds, the d command is executed.

Answer (score 2):

You could use `grep -v`:

```
grep -v '@$'
```

to exclude all lines that match the pattern "line ends with `@`".